# Robot Framework -- Suggestion on better approach -- reading csv as dictionary and passing non-existing key-value as optional argument

Tags: python, testing, automation, automated-tests, robotframework

I'm new to robot framework and learned basics of it through online tutorials and robot framework site.
I'm trying to create a Test framework and facing challenges converting non-existing key-value as an optional argument. It would be really nice if someone could guide me in correct direction.
I want to have a Test Data file in csv format with something like below

| TcNo | A_Data | B_Data | C_Data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TC01 | X1 |  | X3 |
| TC02 | Y1 | Y2 |  |

created a reader as:

```
import pandas as pd
def read_csv_file(csv_path):
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_path,delimiter=',',index_col='TcNo')
    somedict = df.T.to_dict()
    csv_dict = {}
    for key in somedict:
        csv_dict[key] = {k: somedict[key][k] for k in somedict[key] if not pd.isnull(somedict[key][k])}
    return csv_dict
```

Feed it to some TC as Arguments but if the key value doesn't exist  then take Optional Argument. In this example, csv_dict['TC01']['B_Data'] doesn't exist

```
*** Variables ***
TCNo = 'TC01'  #Will be decided dynamically

*** Test Cases***
Execute First TC
    [Arguments]    ${someDict[TCNo]['B_Data']}=some default value
```

Challenges I'm facing:

1. I don't know how to convert a non-existing/blank dictionary value as an Optional Argument in a TC. csv_dict['TC01']['B_Data']

EDIT-Workaround: Okay! This was un-answered so I found a work around. I passed the argument to the keyword with get instead of dictionary indexing. ${csv_dict.get('TC01').get('B_Data','some default value')}
Though not happy with this approach but this is the only solution I could come up

Comment: You say you want a reader which returns a dictionary using pandas. Why do you have the requirement of using pandas?

Comment: It would be best if you split this into two separate questions. A good question should focus on a single problem. First ask about how to convert the data to the format you desired, then once you have the data in that format you can try to use it, and then write a new question when you get stuck.

Comment: Updated the post with only 1 question.